# Safety with wireless MCUs with internal ROM

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, bluetooth, wifi

I read that the ESP32, as long as other MCUs like CC3200, they have an internal ROM not user accessible and usually not open source, used to initialize the device, if I am correct. This means that mine code starts after the ROM initialized everything and give the control to the bootloader+application in flash (external or internal to the device).

Now, if one get really paranoid, is there a threat in using a communication system with some software that is not known? How can one be sure that there is no spy software or not documented backdoor, like it was to be the case in some HDD in the past, from the NSA scandal?

I also know that this apply to any non open source system, so any phone or computer could have such issue in a way greater order of magnitude.

I would like to know just out of curiosity, and I am not at all a security expert.

Comment: It depends on trust really, do you know that a `nop` is actually "no operation", and not a "send my bank details to some mobsters" instruction.

Comment: There is always that possibility - I'm not sure if this question is a good fit here, maybe you should ask that at Information Security SE, but I'm not entirely sure it is a good fit there either.

Comment: So in principle, if you use an MCU which is known to be safe on this point of view, the absolute safe way is to use open source/controllable/self written software to do the nasty wireless job.

Comment: Are you worried about the chip vendor's ROM bootloader being malicious?

Comment: More or less, I am worried on what about is written in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't. Simply too many places to hide it. What you can do is look at its external communications and see if there's anything unexpected there. Maybe take a look at your supply chain.

It's possible, but expensive, to dismantle a unit and reverse-engineer its ROM contents to look for suspicious programs. Or entire other hidden processors. But that only tells you about the one you dismantled.